# Promise delay implementation

Tags: javascript, promise

I've tried to implement delays in Promises this way:

```
function postAndSetContentfulId (client, code) {
  return delay().then(_ => {
    return postToContentful(client, code).then(setCode)
  })
}

function delay () {
  let multipler = Math.floor((count++) / 100) + 1
  let milliseconds = multipler * 2000
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), milliseconds))
}
```

I need to delay an third party API call in order to avoid rate limiting issues. This seems not to be actually working as I get all executed in a bunch.

Comment: what is the value of `count` ?

Comment: Value of multiplier is always 1, until count reach 100. Is that expected?

Comment: Apart from the `milliseconds` calculation, the code looks sounds to me.

Comment: How long are you expecting each delay to be? Any reason why you're not just doing `let milliseconds = count++ * 2000`

Comment: Your implementation is totally correct, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/w1jd584p/

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I'm assuming they're calling the method multiple times and not just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a simple rate limited promise queue I wrote years ago, which has served me very well

```js
const rateLimited = perSecond => {
    const milliSeconds = Math.floor(1000 / perSecond);
    let promise = Promise.resolve(Date.now());
    return fn => promise.then(lastRun => {
        const wait = Math.max(0, milliSeconds + lastRun - Date.now());
        promise = promise.then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, wait))).then(() => Date.now());
        return promise.then(() => fn());
    });
};

const example = rateLimited(2); // 2 per second for the example
let allPromises = Array.from({length:10}, (_, i) => i)
    .map(v => example(() => Promise.resolve(v)));
console.time('Elapsed');
console.log('Started - should take 5 seconds');
Promise.all(allPromises).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
    console.timeEnd('Elapsed');
});
```

For your code, you would use `rateLimited` like

```
const q = rateLimited(20); // 20 per second limit for example
function postAndSetContentfulId(client, code) {
    return q(() => postToContentful(client, code).then(setCode));
}
```